# 18.04: Audacity and UBUNTU_MENUPROXY error message

Tags: gnome, audacity

I just installed Audacity, and every time it starts up I receive the following message:

> UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 could not be found

Followed by:

> audacity could not be found.

It has been removed from the list of recent files.

I recently de-installed LibreOffice and installed OpenOffice and then reversed again (I used to like OO). Otherwise my Ubuntu 18 is standard setup, with GNOME 3.28.2.

Comment: Sorry - I was in a hurry - I have Gnome 3.28.2 - I have corrected the question.

Comment: How did you install Audacity? Step by step?

Comment: I am surprised to find this ten year old post may be relevant https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/12/missing-menus-in-ubuntu-apps-try-this

Comment: Thanks for the reply's - I used the Ubuntu Software installer.